# How does dropout work (with multiple GPUs)?

Tags: neural-network, dropout

Let's say I'm using multiple GPUs and I'm training a neural network that's using dropout. I know that dropout randomly turns off certain nodes in the network for each training sample, and then only updates the weights in the "thinned network," then this seems like a very serial process. How are the weight updates combined during parallelism?

For instance, input #1 removes some ***x*** nodes and input #2 removes some other ***y*** nodes. Let's say ***z*** nodes are common to both instances of the sub-network. Does dropout require backprop to finish for input #1 before beginning feed forward for input #2? Or if it happens parallely, then how are the $z$ nodes updated?

I've already seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030753/training-with-dropout), but the answer in the post doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: I think [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-and-dropout-in-neural-networks-explained-with-pytorch-47d7a8459bcd) post will answer your question, it explains the intuition in detail.

Comment: That post only explains Dropout at a very high level. My question is asking about how the weights are merged afterwards (when training on multiply GPUs). Hence, that post doesn't really help. :/